# Cannot find -lxml2 when trying to run crystal spec

Tags: crystal-lang

Hello I get an error when trying to run crystal spec

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
```

Is this just a dependency error or? I've tried googling but still can't find a solution.

Comment: Please provide more information about the environment, the command you are trying to run etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install libxml development headers. Check this: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/wiki/All-required-libraries

Comment: Thank you for some reason I completely missed that will mark as answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

Or if taking the question literally:

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev
```